# Retrieve emails from Thunderbird's local IMAP store

Tags: ubuntu, imap, thunderbird

I bought a domain name and set up 2 e-mail address linked to this domain name. I used to work with a Ubuntu distribution in the past. On it, I was using Thunderbird as a mail client, and the connection was going to an IMAP server.

I had some personal problems and now that I'm back, I wish to get all the e-mails that were sent to me in the past.

I am still using Ubuntu. I have the address of my IMAP server, email account and password. I have been able to only retrieve some emails (around 700) but I'm missing several.

Does Thunderbird store e-mails locally? And if so, where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If mails are set up to sync there is a local copy. If the copy on the imap server is deleted, the local copy is also deleted, but if you never connected to the imap server again the copy could still be there. Files are under the profile folder

```
~/.thunderbird/<Profile name>/
```

or with Debian/Ubuntu:

```
~/.mozilla-thunderbird/<Profile name>.
```

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Thunderbird#Linux_and_Unix